# Customers who have been cancelled and within five days didn't have REJECTED or APPROVED application

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

| client_id | Date | Resolution |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-15 | CANCELLED |
| 2 | 2022-10-25 | CANCELLED |
| 3 | 2022-10-16 | CANCELLED |
| 3 | 2022-10-17 | REJECTED |
| 4 | 2022-10-08 | CANCELLED |
| 4 | 2022-10-20 | APPROVED |
| 5 | 2022-10-03 | CANCELLED |
| 5 | 2022-10-04 | APPROVED |

Desired results:

| client_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 4 |

I need to get all customers IDs who have been CANCELLED and within five days didn't have REJECTED or APPROVED the application. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
select t1.client_id
from yourtable t1
left join yourtable t2
on t1.client_id = t2.client_id and
   t1.Resolution = 'CANCELLED' and
   t2.Resolution in ('REJECTED', 'APPROVED') and
   t2.date < t1.date + interval '5 days'
where t2.client_id is null
```

Explanation: We search for all `t1` records that were cancelled and do not have a match in `t2` that was either rejected or approved, so, the join condition searches for items with such pairs, defaulting to t2.* being null if there is no such pair for `t1` and then applying a `where` filter that leaves only the `t1` records having no such pairs in the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table t1
WHERE t1.Resolution = 'CANCELLED'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT * FROM table t2
   WHERE t1.client_id = t2.client_id
   AND t2.Resolution IN ('REJECTED', 'APPROVED')
   t2.date < t1.date + interval '5 days'
)
```

Comment: in pgsql no is `dateadd`

Comment: `t2.date < t1.date + interval '5 days'` fixed

Comment: @Nickname_used yeah, sorry, I missed the postgres tag :) there, fixed